# Mongoose limit and sort for populated sub docs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to sort and limit a nested sub doc and after looking up and trying out different solutions I just can't figure it out.

**System**

```
const systemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  data: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Data'
  }],
  ...other
})
```

**Data**

```
const dataSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  measurements: [measurementSchema]
  ...other
})
```

**Measurement**

```
const measurementSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  date: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  },
  ...other
}, { _id : true })
```

As can be seen above; 1 system -> data array -> measurements array

I want to order the measurements by date and limit.

**What I've tried**

Well first thing I tried was using populate options, like so:

```
return System
    .find({ _id: { $in: systemIds } })
    .populate({
      path: 'data',
      populate: {
        path: 'measurements',
        options: {
          sort: { date: 1 },      // <-- doesn't work
          limit: 5                // <-- does work
        }
      }
    })
```

Trying it like this will indeed limit the measurements array, but won't sort it.

After that I tried using aggregate and have a lot of try out code and none of them work, so I left them out of the post.

Using mongoDB 3.4.7

**Sample data**

```
{
    "systems": [
        {
            "data": [
                {
                    "_id": "5c0d87f77f93b06476be9cfd",
                    "measurements": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5c0d894178fc6c64cd36ffeb",
                            "value": "17",
                            "date": "2018-12-09T21:29:37.662Z"
                        }
                        {
                            "_id": "5c0d8952e418d464d6268bfc",
                            "value": "23",
                            "date": "2018-12-09T21:29:54.354Z"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5c0d894b78fc6c64cd36fffb",
                            "value": "34",
                            "date": "2018-12-09T21:29:47.770Z"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5c0d89503de6d564d2d32385",
                            "value": "19",
                            "date": "2018-12-09T21:29:52.293Z"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5c0d894678fc6c64cd36fff3",
                            "value": "16",
                            "date": "2018-12-09T21:29:42.766Z"
                        },

                    ]
                }          
            ],
            "_id": "5c0d87f77f93b06476be9d01"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you update your mongodb version to 3.6 or above?

Answer (score 0):

Populate and sorting has been an issue for `mongoose`:

[Issue 1](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4481) - sort in populate does not work well

[Issue 2](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2202) - Sorting during population of a path in a subdocument  ...

You might be better of doing an aggregation with `$lookup` and sort via `$project` as one [example can be seen here](https://github.com/mrm8488/ama/issues/5)

Comment: Thanks for thinking with me.

I figures that I had to use aggregation but I just can't seem to figure it out..

Comment: Add sample data to your post and I may be able to help you there. Always add sample data for mongo questions. Makes everyones life so much easier and simpler ... other than yours of-course :)

Comment: I included some sample data! :)